# How to assign a value to a column of a df using values from a vector according to a value in another df

Tags: r, loops, assign

I am simulating the growth of a plantation.

I have to fill a df with the volume of 10 trees (one per row) on each year (columns from year 0 to year 6).
I have a function from the package "growthmodels" that computes the volume of the tree for each year or creates a vector with all the values in a range set of years.
I have a df with the age of each tree each year (some trees die and have to be replanted, so their age starts from zero).

Here is a simplified version of the problem:

```
volume <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 6, nrow = 10))
age <- data.frame("y0" = rep(0, 10))
for (y in 2:6){
        d <- sample(1:10, 1)
        d0 <- 10-d
        age <- cbind(age, c(age[1:d, y-1] + rep(1, d), rep(0, d0)))
        names(age)[y] <- paste0("y", y-1)
}
library(growthmodels)
growth <- chapmanRichards(t=1:5, alpha=3, m=.4, k=.4, beta=1)
```

I found the following way to do it, but it is super super slow to execute. Imagine I have to run it for more species and 100 random cases with multiple growth speeds. Do you have suggestions?

```
#inputing normal growth
for (y in 2:6){
        for (t in 1:nrow(volume)) {
                volume[t,y] <- chapmanRichards(t=age[t,y], alpha=3*d, m=.4, k=.4*l, beta=1)
        }
}
```

I need to keep the loop for (y in 2:6) because each year the factors d and l into the chapmanRichards formula have different values.

Comment: My first impulse would be to use a vectorized version of the `chapmanRichards` function: `Vectorize(chapmanRichards, vectorize.args = list("t"))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this in Base-R give the same results as your loop.

```
apply(age,2, function(y) sapply(y,function(x) chapmanRichards(t=x, alpha=3, m=.4, k=.4, beta=1) ))

      y0        y1        y2       y3        y4       y5
 [1,]  0 0.4720002 1.1098773 1.650880 2.0600919 2.354331
 [2,]  0 0.4720002 1.1098773 1.650880 2.0600919 2.354331
 [3,]  0 0.4720002 1.1098773 1.650880 2.0600919 2.354331
 [4,]  0 0.0000000 0.4720002 1.109877 1.6508796 2.060092
 [5,]  0 0.0000000 0.4720002 0.000000 0.4720002 1.109877
 [6,]  0 0.0000000 0.4720002 0.000000 0.4720002 1.109877
 [7,]  0 0.0000000 0.4720002 0.000000 0.4720002 0.000000
 [8,]  0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.000000 0.4720002 0.000000
 [9,]  0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.000000
[10,]  0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.000000
```

**Edit**: to address your comment:

you could achieve this with

```
rbind(
    apply(age[1:3,],2, chapmanRichards, alpha=3, m=.4, k=.4, beta=1),
    apply(age[4:6,],2, chapmanRichards, alpha=3, m=.4, k=.4*7, beta=1),
    apply(age[7:10,],2, chapmanRichards, alpha=3, m=.4, k=0, beta=1)
)
```

Update to the latest comment:

```
t(
cbind(
    apply(age[1:3,],1, chapmanRichards, alpha=3, m=.4, k=.4, beta=1),
    apply(age[4:6,],1, chapmanRichards, alpha=3, m=.4, k=.4*7, beta=1),
    apply(age[7:10,],1, chapmanRichards, alpha=3, m=.4, k=0, beta=1)
)
)

   y0        y1       y2        y3       y4        y5
1   0 0.4720002 1.109877 1.6508796 2.060092 2.3543308
2   0 0.4720002 0.000000 0.4720002 0.000000 0.4720002
3   0 0.4720002 0.000000 0.4720002 0.000000 0.4720002
4   0 0.0000000 0.000000 2.7021553 0.000000 2.7021553
5   0 0.0000000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.000000 2.7021553
6   0 0.0000000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.000000 2.7021553
7   0 0.0000000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.000000 0.0000000
8   0 0.0000000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.000000 0.0000000
9   0 0.0000000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.000000 0.0000000
10  0 0.0000000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.000000 0.0000000
```

Comment: That's great! How would you shape it if you had to use more than one growth function? For example: from row 1 to 3 the formula above, form 4 to 7 with k=.4*7, from 8 to 10 it is 0.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a possible solution. It's hard to know for certain if this gives the result you want since I don't know anything about the `chapmanRichards` function.

Comment: I've also noticed from one of your examples that the function accepts vectors, The code in my edited section has been simplified with this in mind. It should run even faster with the changes.

Comment: Would it be possible to do it with cbind? As my big loop analyze what happens each year and compute volume per column

Comment: so the `apply( ... , 2, ...) ` passed the data into chapmanRichards col-by-col. If you were looking for row-by-row execution then you would want `apply(..., 1, ...)`. I've added an update to the answer

Comment: Thank you Daniel! I'm still not able to fit it into the year loop, I added some explanation to the initial question to clarify. I'm sorry to bother so much!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214713/discussion-between-fiodeno-and-daniel-o).